# How to bypass the login form page in spring security?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using a custom `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`  (which is called before the login page). I am considering the session id of the already logged in user in this filter. If the auth_token exists for the corresponding session id I want to bypass the login page.

How can I do that ?.

Comment: There are a number of spring security projects in github that work. Could one of those help answer your question? I'm not at a computer to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to populate the security context with an authenticated Authencation once you have checked the auth_token. Something like that (in your custom filter):

```
... // first check the existence of the auth_token and extract some information from it like user name and roles
String login = ...
String role = ...
PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken preAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken
                    = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(login, auth_token, Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role)));
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(preAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken);
//At this point : the security context contains an authenticated Authentication and other security filters won't have any impact anymore
```

I don't say it is the best approach for your needs, but it will works with a more or less standard spring security configuration.